Taking a list from a webpage and Displaying It?
I am working on a program that would display a wide range of martial arts. I figured that web scraping would be the best way to do this so that as things grow and evolve, the program would, hopefully, work with the new additions. I had an idea about how to call the wanted unordered list on the page, but the ways I know would require it to have a class/class title, which it doesn't. Any ideas on how to get this list to populate properly in my code? I am fairly new to python, but have some background in other languages
This is the code I found for calling the unordered list:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

MA_list = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_martial_arts"

def MartialArts(): 
    # the target we want to open     
    url = MA_list
      
    #open with GET method 
    resp=requests.get(url) 
      
    #http_respone 200 means OK status 
    if resp.status_code == 200: 
        print("Successfully opened the web page") 
        print("Martial Arts :-\n") 
     
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')     
  
        # l is the list which contains all the text ie the various arts 
        l = soup.find("ul", {"class" : "class_title"}) 
       
        for i in l.findAll("a"): 
            print(i.text) 
    else: 
        print("Error") 
          
MartialArts()

I was expecting the ul to have a class, so this was doomed to fail from the get go. I have a picture below of what I am trying to access. Each of the lists (there are about 30 under the ul block) contains the name of a unique art I am trying to put into a list or loop to display. Wiki page source code div block trying to access and print

BeautifulSoup has a select() method, it takes css selectors, use soup.select() to get a list of all matching elements, and soup.select_one() to get the first matching element.
If the element you are targeting does not have a unique id/class, you can try other selectors like attribute selectors or child combinator.
Basically you can select elements the same way you would in javascript/browser.
In this case we can select all the relevant <a> tags using this selector: soup.select('div.div-col > ul > li > a') or even this soup.select('div.div-col a')
